# Error:400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

**`routes.js`**

```
//require the passport strategy from the folder in the project.
  var passport = require('passport');
  var x = require('./usefile/file');

var requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local',{session: false});

module.exports = function(app){

var auth = express.Router();

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

auth.post('/login', requireLogin, function(req, res){
     x.login(req, res)});
}
```

**`passport.js`**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var config = require('./auth');
var User = require('../models/user');

var localOptions = {
    usernameField: 'email',
};

var localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, function (email, password, done) {
    User.find(
        { email: email }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { error: 'Login failed,Please try again.' });
            }
            if (!isMatch) {
                return done(null, false, { error: 'Login failed, Please try again.' });
            }
            user.comparePassword(function(password, isMatch){
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }
                if(!isMatch){
                    return done(null, false, {error:'Login failed, Please try again.'});
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
});
passport.use(localLogin);
```

Note: My code is not using the `requireLogin` which is used to authenticate from the passport, So it is showing 400 bad request error.

I have referred API docs of passport-local there I found:

```
    app.post('/login', 
      passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
      function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
```

Here `failureRedirect: '/login'` What does it mean?

Please help.

Comment: 400 means that the request that is going is not correct. What request u are sending ?

Comment: I am sending the post request from the frontend to the server at `http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login` This is sending the request I have seen while debugging the code.I have found that, this `requireLogin` is not read.Now how to debug this I am not getting.

Comment: @ParthGhiya please see this in my code. `app.use('/api/auth', auth)`

Comment: Can you please post your code where you have the `passport.use...` function declaration?

Comment: @AdityaJain Seems you don't have the `passwordField` in your `var localOptions` object, also I could not see the usage of this `localOptions` variable anywhere in your code. why?

Comment: @David R Oh!...I forgot to type this code..Thank you..might be this is the only reason why my athenticate is not working..Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdityaJain Great!. I have added this as an answer, Kindly accept it if you get your code working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your code, it seems that you don't have the `passwordField` in your `var localOptions` declaration, also I could not see the usage of this `localOptions` anywhere in your code to make the authentication working using the `passport.js`

Updating the code as required will make you to overcome the 400 bad request error.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: I have implemented rest of my code which with the use of password and localOptins. but the same error is displayed. @David R

Comment: Can you please update you post with your most recent code changes?

Comment: @AdityaJain I could still see that you are having only the `usernameField` in your `localOptions` where you should also have the `passwordField` and the same should get passed to your `new LocalStrategy(....` call.

Comment: But in localOptions I gave because I want email instead of username, Once check this link https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Comment: That's fine, but as per the documentation you should also pass the `password`, Check `Configure Strategy` paragraph under `Usage` section here => https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Comment: okay, under Available Options heading it's written `new LocalStrategy({/* options */, callback}).` where
The available options are:

usernameField - Optional, defaults to 'username'
passwordField - Optional, defaults to 'password'

Comment: I agree, But under the very next heading named "Parameters", It is mentioned as **By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields differently, options are available to change the defaults.**

Comment: So, If I want only username to change as email I did this , but I want to use the default password for password, then it is not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Check your semicolons and commas. There are some extra commas, eg,

```
var localOptions = {
usernameField: 'email',
};
```

should be:

```
var localOptions = {
usernameField: 'email'
};
```

Comment: Extra commas are allowed just fine in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas